# Sort unbound values onto a bound scale?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, nsarray

I have a set of unbound values stored in an array (it's an `NSArray`, if that helps). The values can range from 0 to infinity (in reality the max value is about 100,000,000).

I need to sort the values in my array into a scale of **0 to 20**.

For example, if I have a set of `1000, 3123, 31`, **31** would be **0**, **1000** would be **10** and **3123** would be **20**. The arrays vary in number of members and in max values, so I know if there are a lot of values with different ranges, a lot of those values would take up the same positions on the scale. **Most of the time, the number of items will be way over 20 (the average number of items is about 100).**

*When the number of items is over 20, some of the items should have the same rating.*

I need this for visual representations of songs' populatities per search queries, where those values are the global representations of the song's position on a global chart.

Is it possible to create such an algorithm?

Comment: Is your range 1–20 (as you claim) or 0–20 (as suggested by your example)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731863/mapping-a-numeric-range-onto-another

Comment: I would use a fixed logarithmic scale in such a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right you just want to sort your values ascending and map them to the range of 0 to 20? So you could just count how many values you have (e. g. 11), divide your range by this number - 1 (e. g. 20/(11 - 1) = 2) and assign each value the appropriate number (e. g. 0, 2, 4, 6, 8...)

Comment: Then you will get differences below 1 (but always above 0) like 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2...

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array. Now multiply the index of each item with (20 / ([myArray count] - 1)); Note that count MUST be > 1. I guess you won't have more than 20 items?

Answer (score 0):

Does the percentage like calculation help you?
i.e use the max value as the 100% (i.e 20) and the rest mapped as percentage of the max value.
For your ex:

```
[ 1000 3123 31 ]
(31/3123)*20 = 2
(1000/3123)*20 = 6 (or 7)
(3123/3123)*20 = 20
```

This way the final values (on 0-20 scale) would still have the distribution of the numbers in initial set.