# How to set the value of custom slider

Tags: javascript, c++, math, numbers, formula

I am creating a slider control, I have problems setting the value though

```
_x = 512;
_y = 256;
_width = 128;
_height = 12;
_min = 0;
_max = 10;
```

I do something like,

```
// set the value
_input = 5;
_value = median(_x-(_width/2)+(_input/_max),_x-((_width/2)),_x+((_width/2)))
```

Setting the _input to 5 should put the slider in the middle, but it doesn't, I think I have the calculation wrong in some way.

_x-(_width/2) will give you 0 in percent, 0 in value

_x+(_width/2) will give you 100 in percent, 10 in value. The max.

Comment: what about _value = _x + floor(_input / _max * _width)

Comment: Didn't work :C 
Doing something like _value = _x + floor(7 / _max * _width); gives me 11.95

Comment: I don't see how it could.. floor() should return whole number and in _x you probably have whole number too. So it really shouldn't be 11.95.. _value = _x + floor(7 / _max * _width) = 512 + floor(7 / 10 * 128) = 512 + 89 = 601

Comment: I worked on it since then and finally resolved it. Seems I pretty much had to map the range to the min/max. Followed the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731863/mapping-a-numeric-range-onto-another Thanks in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping `x0 € [_x-_width/2 .. _x+_width/2]` to `sl € [0..10]` linearly and vica versa is not a big deal.

If having `x0`: offset of `-(_x-_width/2)` transforms it to `0.._width`, so a scale of `10/_width` is needed for `0..10`:

```
sl == ( x0 - (_x-_width/2) ) * 10 / _width    // float div unless 10 | _width
```

Reversed:

```
x0 == (_x-_width/2) + sl * _width / 10
```

Take care of `int` vs. `float` divisions and rounding (`+.5`).