# Avoid duplicate values when mapping from one range to another

Tags: c++, math

I implemented a function, that maps a vector of **unique numbers** in the range of `(-109) - 147` to a new range of `0 - 159` folowing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731863/mapping-a-numeric-range-onto-another).

The mapping works fine so far and each all the numbers are transfered to the correct range. I repeated this for a second vector (new range `0 - 119`)

The problem I face is that each pair of numbers (one from each vector) represents a position in a `160x120` image and should therefore be unique. Due to a division that needs to be made in the mapping function that returns a float I used the `round()` to convert to an `int` (116.341 -> 116). But this leads to the problem that point pairs are not unique anymore as:

```
Point     ->    new Range   -> round()
--------------------------------------
177x(-99) -> 117.670x3.9608 -> 118x4 !
176x(-99) -> 117.006x3.9608 -> 118x4 !
```

are correctly mapped to the desired range but are now representing the same point and are not unique anymore. **It is important that:** every point is being mapped to the new range and that there is no information loss, such as that duplicates get discarded. (Point pairs are holding further color information that must be maintained.)

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Unique + "_mapping_" + two variables only = Use `std::map` from `#include <map>`. Edit: Oh so you want to keep duplicates but still use round()?

Comment: The range [0,159]  has 160 integers, so clearly if your vector has more than 160 elements it won't be possible to map its members uniquely to the new range.

Comment: Not quite clear - do you want new range numbers to be unique as well? That's simply is not possible by obvious reason.

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the image and its pixels? Maybe there is an easier solution than to map pixels to other pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to create one-to-one mapping for different ranges of integers (sets of different powers) due to Dirichlet [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

*Note that if reversible mapping would be possible, you might create archiver with infinite compression and squeeze any size file to one or some bytes, then restore it*