# What's the effect of geometry on the final texture output in WebGL?

Tags: webgl

### Updated with more explanation around my confusion

(This is how a non-graphics developer imagines the rendering process!)

I specify a 2x2 sqaure to be drawn in by way of two triangles. I'm going to not talk about the triangle anymore. Square is a lot better. Let's say the square gets drawn in one piece.

I have not specified any units for my drawing. The only places in my code that I do something like that is: canvas size (set to 1x1 in my case) and the viewport (i always set this to the dimensions of my output texture).

Then I call draw().

What happens is this: that regardless of the size of my texture (being 1x1 or 10000x10000) all my texels are filled with data (color) that I returned from my frag shader. This is working each time perfectly.

So now I'm trying to explain this to myself:

- The GPU is only concerned with coloring the pixels.
- Pixel is the smallest unit that the GPU deals with (colors).
- Depending on how many pixels my 2x2 square is mapped to, I should be running into one of the following 3 cases:

  1. The number of pixels (to be colored) and my output texture dims match one to one: In this ideal case, for each pixel, there would be one value assigned to my output texture. Very clear to me.
  2. The number of pixels are fewer than my output texture dims. In this case, I should expect that some of the output texels to have exact same value (which is the color of the pixel the fall under). For instance if the GPU ends up drawing 16x16 pixels and my texture is 64x64 then I'll have blocks of 4 texel which get the same value. I have not observed such case regardless of the size of my texture. Which means there is never a case where we end up with fewer pixels (really hard to imagine -- let's keep going)
  3. The number of pixels end up being more than the number of texels. In this case, the GPU should decide which value to assign to my texel. Would it average out the pixel colors? If the GPU is coloring 64x64 pixels and my output texture is 16x16 then I should expect that each texel gets an average color of the 4x4 pixels it contains. Anyway, in this case my texture should be completely filled with values I didn't intend specifically for them (like averaged out) however this has not been the case.

I didn't even talk about how many times my frag shader gets called because it didn't matter. The results would be deterministic anyway.

So considering that I have never run into 2nd and 3rd case where the values in my texels are not what I expected them the only conclusion I can come up with is that the whole assumption of the GPU trying to render pixels is actually wrong. When I assign an output texture to it (which is supposed to stretch over my 2x2 square all the time) then the GPU will happily oblige and for each texel will call my frag shader. Somewhere along the line the pixels get colored too.

But the above lunatistic explanation also fails to answer why I end up with no values in my texels or incorrect values if I stretch my geometry to 1x1 or 4x4 instead of 2x2.

Hopefully the above fantastic narration of the GPU coloring process has given you clues as to where I'm getting this wrong.

### Original Post:

We're using `WebGL` for general computation. As such we create a rectangle and draw 2 triangles in it. Ultimately what we want is the data inside the texture mapped to this geometry.

What I don't understand is if I change the rectangle from `(-1,-1):(1,1)` to say `(-0.5,-0.5):(0.5,0.5)` suddenly data is dropped from the texture bound to the framebuffer.

I'd appreciate if someone makes me understand the correlations. The only places that real dimensions of the output texture come into play are the call to `viewPort()` and `readPixels()`.

Below are relevant pieces of code for you to see what I'm doing:

```
  ... // canvas is created with size: 1x1
  ... // context attributes passed to canvas.getContext()
  contextAttributes = {
    alpha: false,
    depth: false,
    antialias: false,
    stencil: false,
    preserveDrawingBuffer: false,
    premultipliedAlpha: false,
    failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat: true
  };
  ... // default geometry
    // Sets of x,y,z (for rectangle) and s,t coordinates (for texture)
    return new Float32Array([
      -1.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  // upper left
      -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  // lower left
      1.0,  1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 1.0,  // upper right
      1.0,  -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 // lower right
    ]);  
... 
    const geometry = this.createDefaultGeometry();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, geometry, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
... // binding to the vertex shader attribs
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 20, 0);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 20, 12);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);
... // setting up framebuffer; I set the viewport to output texture dimensions (I think this is absolutely needed but not sure)
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.framebuffer);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(
        gl.FRAMEBUFFER,        // The target is always a FRAMEBUFFER.
        gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,  // We are providing the color buffer.
        gl.TEXTURE_2D,         // This is a 2D image texture.
        texture,               // The texture.
        0);                    // 0, we aren't using MIPMAPs
    gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
... // reading from output texture
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(
        gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture,
        0);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, gl.FLOAT, gl.RED, buffer);
```

Comment: This seems like the most basic WebGL question. Like maybe read the first page of [webglfundamentals.org](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html)

Comment: You've got a lot of stuff on this page. Is there anything specific I should be looking for? If i have a `100x100` texture does it matter if I lay that over a `1x1` square or a `2x2` or `4x4`? I should always have 100 divisions in each direction. right?

Comment: I don't know how to answer you question since I've already answered it. I'll I'd do is say the exact same thing I've already said. You can try reading the other articles there (and read them rather than skim since you clearly couldn't have read that article in the 5 minutes between me linking do it and you commenting that it's too long). Try [this one too](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html) maybe. It doesn't matter whether your writing to the canvas or a texture. In fact the canvas itself is actually a texture internally.

Comment: I'm admitting that I don't understand this. If you've been doing graphics programming for the past 20 years this may come very intuitive to you. However to outsiders it's the farthest thing from that. However, I will go ahead and read your stuff for sure

Comment: I'm going to modify my original post and add my (distorted) rationalization there so hopefully this could reflect how best to answer my question. Then I'm going to come back and read your answer below again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## new answer

I'm just saying the same thing yet again (3rd time?)

Copied from below

> WebGL is destination based. That means it's going to iterate over the pixels of the line/point/triangle it's drawing and for each point call the fragment shader and ask 'what value should I store here`?

It's **destination based**. It's going to draw each pixel exactly once. For that pixel it's going to ask "what color should I make this"

**destination based loop**

```
for (let i = start; i < end; ++i) {
  fragmentShaderFunction();  // must set gl_FragColor
  destinationTextureOrCanvas[i] = gl_FragColor;
```

You can see in the loop above there is no setting any random destination. There is no setting any part of destination twice. It's just going to run from `start` to `end` and exactly once for each pixel in the destination between start and end ask what color it should make that pixel.

How to do you set start and end? Again, to make it simple let's assume a 200x1 texture so we can ignore Y. It works like this

```
 vertexShaderFunction(); // must set gl_Position
 const start = clipspaceToArrayspaceViaViewport(viewport, gl_Position.x);

 vertexShaderFunction(); // must set gl_Position
 const end = clipspaceToArrayspaceViaViewport(viewport, gl_Position.x);

 for (let i = start; i < end; ++i) {
   fragmentShaderFunction();  // must set gl_FragColor
   texture[i] = gl_FragColor;
 }
```

see below for `clipspaceToArrayspaceViaViewport`

What is `viewport`? `viewport` is what you set when you called `gl.viewport(x, y, width, height)

So, set `gl_Position.x` to -1 and +1, viewport.x to 0 and viewport.width = 200 (the width of the texture) then `start` will be 0, `end` will be 200

set `gl_Position.x` to .25 and .75, viewport.x to 0 and viewport.width = 200 (the width of the texture). The `start` will be 125 and `end` will be 175

I honestly feel like this answer is leading you down the wrong path. It's not remotely this complicated. You don't have to understand any of this to use WebGL IMO.

The simple answer is

1. You set gl.viewport to the sub rectangle you want to affect in your destination (canvas or texture it doesn't matter)
2. You make a vertex shader that somehow sets `gl_Position` to clip space coordinates (they go from -1 to +1) across the texture
3. Those clip space coordinates get converted to the viewport space. [It's basic math to map one range to another range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731863/mapping-a-numeric-range-onto-another) but it's mostly **not important**. It's seems intuitive that -1 will draw to the `viewport.x` pixel and +1 will draw to the `viewport.x + viewport.width - 1` pixel. That's what "maps from clip space to the viewport settings means".

It's most common for the viewport settings to be (x = 0, y = 0, width = width of destination texture or canvas, height = height of destination texture or canvas)

So that just leaves what you set `gl_Position` to. Those values are in clip space [just like it explains in this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html).

You can make it simple by doing if you want by converting from pixel space to clip space [just like it explains in this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html)

```
 zeroToOne = someValueInPixels / destinationDimensions;
 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
 clipspace = zeroToTwo - 1.0; 
 gl_Position = clipspace;
```

If you continue the articles they'll also show adding a value [(translation)](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-translation.html) and multiplying by a value [(scale)](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-scale.html)

Using just those 2 things and a unit square (0 to 1) you can choose any rectangle on the screen. Want to effect 123 to 127. That's 5 units so scale = 5, translation = 123. Then apply the math above to convert from pixels to clips space and you'll get the rectangle you want.

If you continue further though those articles you'll eventually get the point where [that math is done with matrices](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html) but you can do that math however you want. It's like asking "how do I compute the value 3". Well, 1 + 1 + 1, or 3 + 0, or 9 / 3, or 100 - 50 + 20 * 2 / 30, or (7^2 - 19) / 10, or ????

I can't tell you how to set `gl_Position`. I can only tell you `make up whatever math you want and set it to *clip space*` and then give an example of converting from pixels to clipspace (see above) as just one example of some possible math.

## old answer

I get that this might not be clear I don't know how to help. WebGL draws lines, points, or triangles two a 2D array. That 2D array is either the canvas, a texture (as a framebuffer attachment) or a renderbuffer (as a framebuffer attachment).

The size of the area is defined by the size of the canvas, texture, renderbuffer.

You write a vertex shader. When you call `gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count)` you're telling WebGL to call your vertex shader `count` times. Assuming primitiveType is `gl.TRIANGLES` then for every 3 vertices generated by your vertex shader WebGL will draw a triangle.  You specify that triangle by setting `gl_Position` in *clip space*.

Assuming `gl_Position.w` is 1, *Clip space* goes from -1 to +1 in X and Y across the destination canvas/texture/renderbuffer. (gl_Position.x and gl_Position.y are divided by `gl_Position.w`) which is not really important for your case.

To convert back to actually pixels your X and Y are converted based on the settings of `gl.viewport`. Let's just do X

```
pixelX = ((clipspace.x / clipspace.w) * .5 + .5) * viewport.width + viewport.x
```

WebGL is destination based. That means it's going to iterate over the pixels of the line/point/triangle it's drawing and for each point call the fragment shader and ask 'what value should I store here`?

Let's translate that to JavaScript in 1D. Let's assume you have an 1D array

```
const dst = new Array(100);
```

Let's make a function that takes a start and end and sets values between

```
function setRange(dst, start, end, value) {
  for (let i = start; i < end; ++i) {
    dst[i] = value;
  }
}
```

You can fill the entire 100 element array with 123

```
const dst = new Array(100);
setRange(dst, 0, 99, 123);
```

To set the last half of the array to 456

```
const dst = new Array(100);
setRange(dst, 50, 99, 456);
```

Let's change that to use clip space like coordinates

```
function setClipspaceRange(dst, clipStart, clipEnd, value) {
  const start = clipspaceToArrayspace(dst, clipStart);
  const end = clipspaceToArrayspace(dst, clipEnd);
  for (let i = start; i < end; ++i) {
    dst[i] = value;
  }
}

function clipspaceToArrayspace(array, clipspaceValue) {
  // convert clipspace value (-1 to +1) to (0 to 1)
  const zeroToOne = clipspaceValue * .5 + .5;

  // convert zeroToOne value to array space
  return Math.floor(zeroToOne * array.length);
}
```

This function now works just like the previous one except takes clip space values instead of array indices

```
// fill entire array with 123
const dst = new Array(100);
setClipspaceRange(dst, -1, +1, 123);
```

Set the last half of the array to 456

```
setClipspaceRange(dst, 0, +1, 456);
```

Now abstract one more time. Instead of using the array's length use a setting

```
// viewport looks like `{ x: number, width: number} `

function setClipspaceRangeViaViewport(dst, viewport, clipStart, clipEnd, value) {
  const start = clipspaceToArrayspaceViaViewport(viewport, clipStart);
  const end = clipspaceToArrayspaceViaViewport(viewport, clipEnd);
  for (let i = start; i < end; ++i) {
    dst[i] = value;
  }
}

function clipspaceToArrayspaceViaViewport(viewport, clipspaceValue) {
  // convert clipspace value (-1 to +1) to (0 to 1)
  const zeroToOne = clipspaceValue * .5 + .5;

  // convert zeroToOne value to array space
  return Math.floor(zeroToOne * viewport.width) + viewport.x;
}
```

Now to fill the entire array with 123

```
const dst = new Array(100);
const viewport = { x: 0, width: 100; }
setClipspaceRangeViaViewport(dst, viewport, -1, 1, 123);
```

Set the last half of the array to 456 there are now 2 ways. Way one is just like the previous using 0 to +1

```
setClipspaceRangeViaViewport(dst, viewport, 0, 1, 456);
```

You can also set the viewport to start half way through the array

```
const halfViewport = { x: 50, width: 50; }
setClipspaceRangeViaViewport(dst, halfViewport, -1, +1, 456);
```

I don't know if that was helpful or not.

The only other thing to add is instead of `value` replace that with a function that gets called every iteration to supply `value`

```
function setClipspaceRangeViaViewport(dst, viewport, clipStart, clipEnd, fragmentShaderFunction) {
  const start = clipspaceToArrayspaceViaViewport(viewport, clipStart);
  const end = clipspaceToArrayspaceViaViewport(viewport, clipEnd);
  for (let i = start; i < end; ++i) {
    dst[i] = fragmentShaderFunction();
  }
}
```

Note this is the exact same thing that is said in [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html) and clearified somewhat in [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html).

Comment: Starting to understand this. I'm going to ask a lot of clarifying questions.

Comment: I didn't even know about 'w'. If i'm understanding this is the 4th value in gl_Position returned from the vertex shader. I have set that to 1. When you say `Clip space goes from -1 to +1 in X and Y across the destination` is that because I set w to 1? Or is it because my geometry is from (-1,-1) to (1,1)?

Comment: In this formula `pixelX = ((clipspace.x / clipspace.w) * .5 + .5) * viewport.width + viewport.x` what is viewport.x? Let's say I want to find out pixelX for (0.5,1) on my geometry. In this case the clipSpace.x would be 0.5? and say my texture is 200w x 100h. What would the value for viewport.x be?

Comment: After looking at your `setClipspaceRange` I think I know what viewport.x is. It is the iterator value when I go over the texels in my texture width?

Comment: To test the effect of 'w' I went and changed my geometry to be (-2,-2)->(2,2) and accordingly made this change: `gl_Position = vec4(position, 2.0);` (changed w to 2.0 from 1.0). And everything still worked! starting to get a hang of this

Comment: I am very appreciative of how you're helping me always. I think now I have a much better understanding of the subject. The concepts are very fundamental (as in crucial to understanding) but not basic (as in simple) at all. I looked at the other 2 links again. I still would not have understood this without the formulas/sample code you presented above

Comment: All of this info is in the articles I linked to.  One of the use cases of gl_Position.w is covered [here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective.html). Another use case is covered [here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective-correct-texturemapping.html). Please consider taking some time to read through all of the articles there.

Comment: using `gl_Position.w` for any GPGPU reason is not common as far as I know so you even mentioning it makes me think you might be going down the wrong path. There is zero need to set `gl_Position.w` to anything other than 1.0 for anything GPGPU related or anything 2D related.

Comment: The formula above seems derivable to anyone that's done any short amount of programming. It has nothing do with graphics. If it says "coordinates are in clip space and clip space goes from -1 to 1" somewhere. And somewhere else it says "clip space gets converted to pixels based on the viewport settings (x, y, width, height)". Then it seems like most programmers would intuit the formula from clip space to pixels is `(clipspace.x * .5 + .5) * viewport.width + viewport.x` or they could use a common function that maps a value from one range to another.

Comment: Also `viewport.x` is not an iterator value. It's a constant. It's the value you passed to `gl.viewport` as in `gl.viewport(x, y, width, height)`. In the example above we just made an object `{x: somevalue, width: somevalue}` to represent the values passed to `gl.viewport`.  `viewport.x` is whatever you set it to. Your example of texture being 200x100, well the example is only 1D above so in that case your texture is `const dst = new Array(200)`.  `viewport.x` and `viewport.width` are 100% up to you. Same in WebGL.

Comment: Honestly I think this answer is leading you down the wrong path. I think it's making WebGL more confusing. You don't need to know any of this to use WebGL IMO and thinking of it this way will only make it seem harder than it is.

Comment: I'm actually very glad that I bumped into making the change to my geometry to get a chance to understand this concept. I may not ever have to change my geometry or `w` for gpgpu but understanding it was super important... and I'm not sure i'm still getting this

Comment: Using your formula it's explainable why when I changed my geometry to be(-0.5,-0.5)-(0.5,0.5) i suddenly ended up with less texels populated. Applying your formula above to say a viewport of (0,0,200,100) would give me a pixel area of (50,25)-(150,75) . This is like moving the x,y my viewport and also shrinking it

Comment: When I said that formula helped me understand I didn't mean the formulation but rather how the clipspace, x, w, and viewport were being related

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180123/discussion-between-jeff-saremi-and-gman).

Comment: `gl_position` needs to be between -1,1. This is one of the parts I didn't know about. I think this explains the 0.5 in your pixel value determination formula (length is 2). My testing and conclusions were flawed because I assumed the coordinates passed to `vertexAttribPointer()` will automatically be scaled to `[0,1]` or `[-1,1]`. Didn't think that it is the vertex shader's job to set the `gl_position` to that. Thanks a lot for being so patient

Comment: that the very first thing mentioned in the articles I linked to. not what good sign ☹️