# calculate color corresponding to numbers using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a data of numbers, i need to plot it into a grid and color each block according to the number. The bigger numbers should have darker shades of blue and smaller should have lighter shades of blue. How to find the corresponding color?

Comment: You can use `background: rgb(num, num, num)` but we would need more info on this. You can use this for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503998/how-to-create-custom-palette-with-custom-color-for-material-design-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HSL` colors. Where the first argument is the hue, the second is the saturation and the third the light value. On the color wheel, blue is located at 240º, so you can set the H value to be 240. You can then set the saturation to be 100%, and the light value to be a percentage based on the input number (calculated by taking the current data point on the max).

See example below:

```js
const data = [];
const MAX = 100;

const getColor = (n, max, error) => {
 return `hsl(240, 100%, ${(1-n/max) * 100}%)`
}

let html = "";
for(let i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
  html += `<div class='box' style="background-color: ${getColor(i, MAX)}">${i}</div>`
}

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to add boundaries, you want to condense the output of `0-100` to be between `0+bl to 100-br`. This type of mapping can be done using a formula [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731863/mapping-a-numeric-range-onto-another), where `bl` is the boundary from the left (ie: the lowest blue colour) and `br` is the boundary from the right (ie: the darkest blue colour).

```js
const data = [];
const MIN = 0; // min value in data (Math.min(...data))
const MAX = 100; // max value in data (Math.max(...data))

const map = (is, ie, os, oe, val) => os + ((oe - os) / (ie - is)) * (val - is);
const getColor = (n, min, max, bl=0, br=0) => {
 const l = 100 - map(min, max, bl, 100-br, n);
 return `hsl(240, 100%, ${l}%)`
}

let html = "";
for(let i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
  html += `<div class='box' style="background-color: ${getColor(i, MIN, MAX, 10, 40)}">${i}</div>`
}

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: this is working, but the smaller numbers are giving white color. Can i set boundaries ?

Comment: @Mmit I've updated my answer which allows you to enter boundaries