# How can I change a value inside of a setter?

Tags: java, getter-setter

In my code, I'm getting an "interview score" input between 0-10 from an array. I am supposed to map 0 to 0 and 10 to 100, so basically **multiply the interview score by 10**.

My constructor for the object is

```
public Person(String firstName, String lastName, double interview) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.gpa = gpa;
    this.interview = interview;
}
```

and my object is

```
Person s1 = new Person("name", "surname", 3.5, 8);
```

Here, 8 being the interview score and 3.5 being the GPA score (not necessarily a part of my question).

In my get and set methods I'm using

```
public double getInterview() {
    return interview;
}

public void setInterview(double interview) {
    this.interview = interview*10;
}
```

Expecting it to multiply by 10 so I can use it in my getTotalPoints method in the same class which is:

```
points = getGpa()*gpaWeight +  getInterview()*intWeight;
```

but here it takes the interview score as **8**, **not 80**.

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks

(PS I don't really know anything about maps etc. so I don't know if it'll work here, I'd appreciate it if any answer was given in this format)

Comment: This happens because as you initialize your class, your value is set to whatever the input is: ```this.interview = interview;``` therefore your logic that is used in your setter is not used. Perhaps, add that logic to your constructor too (```this.interview = interview*10;```) or call your setter instead.

Comment: @MarcusSlover Brilliant! Thanks for the answer. If you want reply as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the constructor to set the interview value instead of the setter method setInterview().

Use setInterview() method to set the interview value or modify the constructor as below:

```java
public Person(String firstName, String lastName, double interview) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.gpa = gpa;
  this.interview = interview * 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that between your **constructor** and **setter** there is **inconsistency** on the **scale of representation** of the Interview attribute.

In the constructor:

```
this.interview = interview;
```

so here you work in a range from **0 to 10**

Whereas in the setter

```
this.interview = interview*10;
```

so here you work in the range from **0 to 100**

You can either set the value in the 0-100 scale and use it that way, or set it in the 0-10 scale and each time you use it you have to remember to map it to the 0-100 scale. I think the best solution is the former.

Regarding mapping from one range to another, you can take inspiration from this answer:
[Mapping a numeric range onto another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731863/mapping-a-numeric-range-onto-another)

Answer (score 1):

You are never calling the `setInterview` function. If you don't call it then how the value will change.
Assuming you are only passing the values using `constructor`. I would suggest o to call the `setInterview` inside the `constructor`.

```
public Person(String firstName, String lastName, double interview) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.gpa = gpa;
    setInterview(interview); // or you can simply assign the value here 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can immediately initialize the value of the interview, if this parameter is used only in the form in which you wrote it.

```
this.interview = interview * 10;
```

And you will no longer need the setInterview() method