# What is the syntax used for the library that contains the built-in map function on Arduino?

Tags: c, arduino, microcontroller, libraries

I have been looking across various sites and I cannot seem to find much information regarding the information on the Arduino function libraries. I am using an HCS12 microcontroller (MC9S12DG256B) that has fewer libraries built into the bootloader. One of these lacking functionalities includes a built-in map function. I am specifically asking about the math and syntax that the Arduino utilizes in the library that contains the map function. How does Arduino define the map function? Here is what I am trying to define on my micro written in Arduino syntax.

```
int pot;    
int PWM = map(pot,0,1023,3300,5700);
```

Comment: There is an answer and really good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5732390/4902099)

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/

```cpp
map(value, fromLow, fromHigh, toLow, toHigh)
```

> value: the number to map.
> fromLow: the lower bound of the value’s current range.
> fromHigh: the upper bound of the value’s current range.
> toLow: the lower bound of the value’s target range.
> toHigh: the upper bound of the value’s target range.

The math function is also given

> ```cpp
> long map(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max) {
>   return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
> }
> ```