# is there function to convert variable to some range?

Tags: c++

I am tryingto convert one number in my code from some range to other range. i know there is a function to do this but i don't remember what is this function.
here is part of code where i need to do this:
`void bossBattle()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>

enum stan { koniec, bitwa, swobodny, sklep, EQ, konsola, lootowanie, Bitwaboss};

void bossBattle()
{
    COORD pasekZycia;
    pasekZycia.X = 10;
    pasekZycia.Y = 0;
    COORD przeciwnik;
    przeciwnik.X = 30;
    przeciwnik.Y = 30;
    COORD menu;
    menu.X = 20;
    menu.Y = 70;
    int HPbosa = 1000;
    int gdzie = 0;
    int test = 0;
    while (aktualny == stan::Bitwaboss)
    {
        if (gdzie == 0)
        {
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(outcom, pasekZycia);
            for (int i = 0; i < HPbosa; i++)
            {
                std::cout << "*";
            }
            gdzie = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

entire code is to long and has nothing to do with my problem

can you please geve me name of function to do this or if it don't exist, hot do i do this.

Comment: What are you trying to convert? Can you give an example?

Comment: Have you looked at `#include<algorithm>`? Here is an awesome introduction. https://youtu.be/2olsGf6JIkU?si=QHjPSBwdR9iykDli

Comment: i try to convert HPbosa to number in range 0 - 250 so it fits on the screen

i haven't lookd in the libary give me moment i'll lok at it

Comment: `HPbosa / 4`? You must have a very wide screen.

Comment: maby 250 is wide but i know that shuch function exist becuse i used it in the past. i simply don't remember how it is called, and i can any time change it to the other range like 0-100 or 0-150

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping a numeric range onto another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731863/mapping-a-numeric-range-onto-another) TLDR; `f(x) = (x-x0)/dx*dy+y0`

Comment: yes this answer i need thanks